# How can you use a mutex between c# and java processes?

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, ipc

I would like to do a consumer-producer pattern using memory mapped files from java to c#. 
I need a low latency way of signalling from java to c# to read the data.

In c# you can use a named Mutex (new Mutex(true,"sharedMutex1")) between processes and use Mutex.WaitOne() and 
 Mutex.ReleaseMutex() to control between processes.

How can I do this from a Java process?

edit: I am aware you can use a File Lock to do it but I would like to keep away from the file system to keep latency low.

edit: another option is to use c++ via JNI. So I guess I am asking now if it can be done in Java directly?

Comment: Have you asked mighty google for the answer? Have you *tried* anything yourself?

Comment: i dont see anything in java that can do it thanks.

Comment: Literal first result on google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41866893/how-to-consume-a-system-mutex-shared-by-c-sharp-and-java-programs

Comment: thanks so you need to use c++ via JNI. is there a java solution without resorting to this?

Comment: If you *really* need a low latency solution, use a busy wait on a value in the shared memory region. Make sure the value is alone on its own cache line to avoid false sharing, and that it's properly aligned. Use interlocked compare exchange to flip it (`Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref *ptr, 1, 0)`). You'll have your own mutex implementation without involving the kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple options:

- Using a file based lock, as you mentioned
- Using a memory mapped file, and a protocol based on low level memory access. This is hard to get right, and you need access 'sun.misc.Unsafe' operations. I would look into libraries like [OpenHFT](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes), which gives you reasonable API over the unsafe operation. However, it is still hard.
- Use JNI to use the Win32 / unix API's for inter process locks. I recommend to use something like [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) or [JNR](https://github.com/jnr/), which allows you to call C apis without writing the JNI C part.

Here a example with JNA which calls into the WIN32 lock API:

```
/**
 * Definitions of the Win32 API. JNA has some for windows, so check first
 * In case CreateMutex is not included.
 */
public interface Kernel32Ex extends Kernel32 {
    WinNT.HANDLE CreateMutex(
            WinBase.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpMutexAttributes,
            boolean bInitialOwner,
            String lpName
    );

    boolean ReleaseMutex(
            WinNT.HANDLE hMutex
    );
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // The binding. Create it once
    final Kernel32Ex Win32 = Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32Ex.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);

    WinNT.HANDLE handle = Win32.CreateMutex(null,
            true,
            "My-Mutext");
    if (handle == null) {
        throw new Win32Exception(Win32.GetLastError());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Holding the win32 mutex");
        Win32.ReleaseMutex(handle);
    }
}
```